# Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: epel/x86_64. Please verify its path and try again

Tags: ansible, vagrant, yum, rhel7, epel

I am trying to create a virtual machine with RHEL 7.7 using vagrant. I am very new with vagrant.

When I did `vagrant up` many different libraries and dependencies are downloaded and installed.

Among those one is Ansible. The virtual machine failed to start because it failed to install Ansible.
[image]

[image]

When i tried to execute a yum command, its not even able to find yum.

What is the problem here and how can i resolve this ?

thanks

Comment: can you do following : first delete the vm now (vagrant destroy) then run vragrant up --no-provision, ssh into the VM (vagrant ssh) run sudo yum update, if ok exit and run vagrant provision to rerun your script

Comment: As it turns out, it was a VPN issue. I dont know how but it works only on a certain VPN.

Comment: which network setting do you apply ?

Comment: I did not use any specific network settings. I just changed my organisations vpn to Sydney and it worked.